# Extremely puzzling probability question.......

Tags: probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conjunction fallacy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134235/conjunction-fallacy)

Alice is thirty-one years old, single, outspoken and very bright. She majored 
in finance. As a student she was deeply concerned with issues of 
discrimination and social justice, and participated in anti-nuclear 
demonstrations.

Consider the following two alternatives: 
 (I) Alice is active in the feminist movement. 
 (II) Alice works in a bank and is active in the feminist movement.

Which of the above two alternatives is more probable? Choose one of the 
following options.

A. (I).

B. (II).

C. Equally likely.